# Шрифт в TextView Android

Tags: android, шрифты, android-textview

Создаю динамически элемент TextView. Нужно установить шрифт, который использует остальная часть программы. При вызове этого кода приложение падает.

```
            TextView textDis = new TextView(this.getContext());
            textDis.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
            textDis.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));
            textDis.setTextSize(18);
            //Ошибочный код ниже:
            textDis.setTypeface(getResources().getFont(R.font.fira_sans), Typeface.BOLD);
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для шрифтов рекомендую использовать папку `assets` и устанавливать вот так:

```
textDis.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "my_font_bold.ttf");
```

Кроме того, чтобы избежать лагов (а если у вас много текстов со своим шрифтом они будут), рекомендую шрифт кэшировать, например так:

```
public class TypeFaces {

    //---Кэширование шрифта---
    private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(Context c, int type) {
        String name;
        if (type == 1)
            name = "my_font.ttf";
        else
            name = "my_font_bold.ttf";

        synchronized (cache) {
            if (!cache.containsKey(name)) {
                String path = name;
                try {
                    Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), path);
                    cache.put(name, t);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return cache.get(name);
        }
    }
}
```

И использовать так:

```
 textDis.setTypeface(TypeFaces.get(this, 2));
```

Если у вас много текстов, самым лучшим вариантом будет создать кастомный `TextView`, где в `init()` шрифт будет будет выставляться автоматически.

Либо можно воспользоваться методом из [support библиотеки](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat):

```
textDis.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.my_font));
```