# Кастомная кнопка. Анимация одной кнопки при нажатии на другую

Tags: java, android

В меню игры нужна кнопка для выбора режима игры. Обычный выпадающий spinner не подходит. Захотелось вот такую штуку:

```
                 Начать игру 
                 < Режим 1 > 
                  Рекорды
                 Настройки
                   Выход
```

Либо стрелки будут вызывать анимацию движения кнопки и вместо Режим 1 выйдет кнопка Режим 2. Важно чтобы была плавная анимация. 
Вот думаю как же это реализовать. Ну первая стрелка это кнопка , посередине ImageView ? или не кликабельная кнопка описанная в xml как анимированная. При нажатию на стрелку нужно вызвать анимацию ухода `ImageView` в правую часть экрана и прихода  уже с другим текстом с левой части экрана. (даже лучше использовать `TextView` с `backgroud`)  Ну в общем я думаю понять, что я хочу совсем не сложно. Хочу понять как это реализовать правильно, чтобы не учиться на своих ошибках, времени на это к сожалению нет.

Попробовал класс Animation, в нём 4 типа анимации, вот гифка вначале [статьи](https://%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80.%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8/android-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC-button). Есть вариант с уходом кнопки вправо и возвратом так же справа, не знаю можно ли её адаптировать так чтобы возврат был с левой стороны экрана и вообще можно ли в процессе анимации в нужный момент менять текст кнопки?

Comment: Как я понял, вы хотите на стрелки сделать анимированную смену режимов игры? Сделайте `LinearLayout` с `ImageView`/`TextSwitcher`/`ImageView`. Посмотрите про свитчер здесь: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/textswitcher.php

Comment: Да, не плохо конечно, но двигается только текст, а кнопки имеют и фон. Это конечно не критично, но хотелось бы знать какие есть варианты, чтобы не только текст анимировать.

Comment: И с текстом тоже есть проблемка. Я подключаю две анимации, одна это слайд вправо, а другая слайд из левой стороны. Это две готовые анимации. И подключил на правую стрелку. И эффект такой: текст текущий уезжает вправо и приходит слева новый текст.  И вот проблема: при нажатии на левую, нужен слайд обратный. сами анимации я сделал. Но `textSwitcher` то один... Как сделать, так чтобы на одном и том же `textSwitcher` была другая анимация при нажатии на другую кнопку менее затратным путем.

Comment: И есть еще проблема: активити полностью прогрузилось, все кнопки прогрузились и только свитчер пустой и через  0.3 сек в нем появляется текст. Долго, не красиво. Не знаю как решить. У этого элемента нет атрибута text чтобы задать начальный текст.

Comment: Если вам `TextSwitcher` подходит и лучше предложений не появится, чуть позже оформлю ответ, в тч с обратной анимацией. Не понял, что вы имели ввиду про фон кнопок?

Comment: Обычно текст появляется сразу. Возможно у вас где-то задержка в анимации или подгружается кастомный шрифт

Comment: Ну я разобрался с проблемой задержки. Да это кастомный шрифт. Проблема была в том, что при первом появлении текст немного задерживался и еще задержка от анимации. Но я подключение анимации убрал из onCreate и перенес в кнопку правой стрелку и установку обратной анимации на кнопку левой стрелки. В итоге изначально текст появляется быстро и без анимации, а потом уже по нажатию на стрелку подключается та или иная анимация. Эти две проблемы решены.

Comment: А вот насчет фона. Есть кнопка у неё есть backgroud, вот хочется чтобы не только текст уезжал вправо, а вся кнопка. `textSwitcher` так устроен что анимируется только текст, а установленный фон стоит на месте.

Comment: шрифт лучше кэшировать. А обратную анимацию делал через `ReverseInterpolator`, но пока доступа к коду нет, не помню как. Задавайте бэк не `switcher`'у, а тексту (в `makeText()`)

Comment: вот эта статья дает понять, что можно анимировать этим же инструментом и view целиком, но я пока немного не понял как   https://ru-code-android.livejournal.com/5392.html

Comment: Вот посмотреть в ответе про применение `ReverseInterpolator` было бы интересно. А то я создал создал два xml с обратными анимациями, а можно наверно имеющиеся анимации пропустить через интерполятор.

Comment: говоря   `makeText()`   вы имели ввиду, наверно, `makeView()`  . Да, я в нем установил  `setBackgroundResource` и теперь всё как надо. Шрифт у меня установлен там же из ресурсов, где его  мне еще кешировать то?

Comment: да) посмотрите, тут недавно отвечал про кэширование https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/844916/%D0%A8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82-%D0%B2-textview-android/844929#844929

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `LinearLayout` с `ImageView`/`TextSwitcher`/`ImageView`:

Про `TextSwitcher` можно почитать [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/textswitcher.php).

Анимацию в одну сторону устанавливайте так:

```
in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left); 
out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

в другую, вам понадобится такой класс:

```
public class ReverseInterpolator implements Interpolator { 
    @Override 
    public float getInterpolation(float paramFloat) { 
         return Math.abs(paramFloat -1f); 
    } 
}
```

использовать, прямая:

```
in.setInterpolator(new LinearInterPolator());
out.setInterpolator(new LinearInterPolator());
```

обратная:

```
in.setInterpolator(new ReverseInterpolator ());
out.setInterpolator(new ReverseInterpolator ());
```

**Другой вариант:**

Не использовать `TextSwitcher`, а собрать анимацию самому. Плюсы - можно анимировать любые `View`. Минусы - надо самому прописывать всю анимацию. Хотя это не так сложно. В приведенных вами ссылках есть варианты. Если что-то по ним не понятно - спросите.